# Проверка целостности файла php.

Tags: 1с, php

Всем доброго дня. Недавно на моей работе мне дали задние произвести синхронизацию карточек товара с 1с бухгалтерией. Есть сервер с сайтом магазина и удаленный сервер с 1с бухгалтерией, на втором лежит общедоступный файл с каталогом товаров, кот экспортируется из 1с, с помошью скрипта он скачивается на 1-й и обрабатывается, при этом возникает проблема с блокировкой файла, если запрос с сервера сайта совпадет со временем изменения/перезаписи файла каталога, могут возникнуть проблемы. Как можно предотвратить эту проблему? Гугл молчит, я пока додумался сравнивать хэш удаленного файла в начале скачки и в конце скрипта, если они не совпадают, то след произошла коллизия, но мне кажется, что это не решение проблемы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После формирования cvs файла записываем в отдельный файл его хэш.

```
Функция МД5(файл)
    ScrCtrl = СоздатьОбъект("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl");
    ScrCtrl.Language = "vbscript";
    ScrCtrl.AddCode("
    |Function Hash()
    |Dim crypt: Set crypt = CreateObject(""CAPICOM.HashedData"")
    |crypt.Algorithm = 3
    |Dim stream: Set stream = CreateObject(""ADODB.Stream"")
    |stream.Type = 1 ' adTypeBinary
    |stream.Open
    |stream.LoadFromFile("""+файл+""")
    |Do Until stream.EOS : crypt.Hash stream.Read() : Loop
    |Hash = crypt.Value
    |End Function
    |");
    рез = ScrCtrl.Run("Hash");
    Возврат рез;
КонецФункции
```

Взято [здесь](http://infostart.ru/public/82506/)
Осталось только скачать хэш, скачать файл, проверить совпадение на сервере. Повторить в случае провала.

---

Можно так же  перед скачиванием открыть сокет на файл дампа и прочитать только http-заголовок last-modifitired. Сейчпс протестировал на localhost: apache вполне успешно вернул время последнего изменения файла test.txt

```
// Java
try {
    byte buf[]=new byte[2048];
    Socket sock=new Socket("localhost", 80);
    InputStream ins=sock.getInputStream();
    OutputStream outs=sock.getOutputStream();
    outs.write("GET http://localhost/test.txt HTTP/1,0\r\n\r\n".getBytes());
    ins.read(buf);
    System.out.println(new String(buf));
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Результат

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 22 Mar 2012 19:35:23 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Thu, 22 Mar 2012 13:06:15 GMT
ETag: "437d4-2c-4bbd492b06dd4"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 44
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain

#! /usr/bin/python
```

Потом уже file_get_contents скачивать. Можно даже не пытаться распарсить точное время **Last-Modified: Thu, 22 Mar 2012 13:06:15 GMT**, главное, что если на начало закачки и на конец разные значения, то надо снова качать.

Comment: Хороший способ, подходит, но есть один нюанс, за сторону с 1с отвечает человек заказчика, не известна его квалификация и сможет ли он вообще скрипт написать, хотелось бы все таки узнать как можно сделать это самому? с помошью php или скриптов bash, без явной помощи. Но за способ спасибо, если человек на стороне заказчика грамотный, все решится сразу.

Comment: Похоже что вариант с заголовками подходит больше всего, спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте делать импорт в магазин по расписанию. И сделайте так, чтобы это расписание не совпадало с расписанием экспорта файла из 1С.

Comment: К сожалению, не вариант, заказчик ни в какую не хочет ограничивать себя, мотивируя это тем, что он нам платит и след это наща забота. Единственное, в чем он пошел на встречу, так это предоставление файла в формате csv в доступном дял скрипта месте.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на ваш вопрос очень прост. После выгрузки данных из 1С формируйте файл-маркер успешного завершения. затем
скрипом перед загрузкой проверяете наличие этого файла-маркера. Если файл есть, значит забираете, если нет просто завершаете работу скрипта. После успешной загрузки не забывайте удалять маркер.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю такую схему, что если произойдет коллизия с доступом к файлу именно когда он будет скачиваться? Файл-маркер от этого же никак не спасет. И вообще, чем плох способ с проверкой хэш файла в начале и конце скрипта? Информации по этой теме уж очень мало в инете.

Comment: А почему вы считаете что плох? Хэш-суммы очень широко используют для проверки целостности файлов. Вот только какие хэши вы сравниваете не очень понятно.

А вообще - вы это делаете по расписанию или в произвольные периоды времени. И какой протокол доступа к файлу?

Comment: Делается это по расписанию из cron каждый час, файл тупо читается file_get_content(), хэш файла определяется функцией md5_file().Вообще не судите строго мои способ, т.к. я раньше ничего подобного не делал вот и приходится импровизировать как знаю)

Comment: Файл по сети читается? FTP, NFS, SMB/CIFS? Туда доступ ro или rw? Попробуйте перед импортом файла просто копировать его к себе во временную папку, а оттуда его `file_get_contents()` считывать.

Comment: Вообще заказчик сам не сказал, как можно осуществить доступ к каталогу 1с, все что он сказал, так это то, что может предоставить файл в открытом доступе в их каталоге, т.е. я вообще без понятия, какое у них там оборудование и как можно организовать считывание. Сам пока что проверял с файлом на удаленном хосте, читал его с помошью file_get_content('http://testsite.ru').

Comment: Просто берите и делайте как есть. Нарушение целостности маловероятно, а если вы всё-же опасаетесь его - тогда вы должны иметь подпись **оригинального** файла. А сформировать её можно **только на стороне сервера который формирует csv**, процедурой предолженной @ReinRaus